# jQuery preventDefault() not working and syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I'm trying to make a form validation using jQuery etc.. 
I'm trying to use the event.preventDefault(); function to prevent the form from submitting the default way.

It doesn't seem to be working.

I am also trying to make an if statement that checks if its a valid email adress but it's giving be syntax error for some reason.

Hoow do I fix these issues?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    input {
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 7px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    label {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    #submitButton {
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

    <form id="validationForm">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" />

        <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
        <input name="phone" />

        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" />

        <label for="pass">Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" />

        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        $("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
    // this is the preventdefault that isn't working.
            event.preventDefault();

            function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
                var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
                return pattern.test(emailAddress);
            }
    // It's giving me syntax error for the '{' in the beginning of this if //statement. 
            if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val()) {
                alert("hello");
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where's the error occurring? i think your regex statement might be invalid `...$/i`? should that be `...$/,"i")`?

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after condition;

Comment: This `new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|..........FFEF])))\.?$/i)` should just be `/^((([a-z]|\d|..........FFEF])))\.?$/i`

Comment: What default are you trying to prevent? The form has no action so what is it doing by 'default'?

Comment: [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [jshint](http://jshint.com/) can be very helpful to avoid having these kinds of embarrassing questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `)` in this line:

```
if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val()) {
```

Should be:

```
if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())) {
```

Notice you have 4 `(` and only 3 `)`? That's the issue. Look into using an IDE when editing code, it would have picked up this issue instantly.

**Edit**

Also, the syntax error was causing the `event.preventDefault()` to not fire, so this fix will solve that as well.

Comment: Sorry for that lol. Also, others are saying there's an issue with your regex, might want to look into that as well. Right now, everything I put into the email field is valid...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code syntax needs some correction:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#validationForm").on('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
      }

      if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())) {
        alert("hello");
      }
  });
</script>
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8jj8nsd/)